# HATEOAS links returning 4xx?

Tags: hateoas

I have implemented HATEOAS feature in my REST server: it now returns a collection of links as a part of response, like this

```js
"hrefs": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "/v1/data/default"
    },
    {
      "rel": "domain",
      "href": "/v1/domains/default"
    },
    {
      "rel": "root",
      "href": "/v1/data/default"
    },
    {
      "rel": "attributes",
      "href": "/v1/data/default/.attributes"
    }
  ]
```

I now want to advertise additional resources, but the problem is their usage requires specification of obligatory query arguments (`?min=value1&max=value2`). As it is not known what values would user want to provide, adding bare resource URL would lead to error 4xx when followed. What is considered the best practice?

1. Add "broken" links anyway,
2. Make the query arguments optional, so bare URLs can be followed successfully from HATEOAS hrefs (what's the best return status code?),
3. Refrain from advertising those links.

Comment: Returning 404 for a malformed query is inappropriate, you should return 400 instead. If these attributes are truly party of the resource identity, they should be part of the base URL, and not query parameters.

Comment: Indeed, I have edited the question to avoid 404. In any case, if the query parameters become part of the resource name, it doesn't make easier to advertise them: the complete link URL is still not known at the time of hrefs generation.